# How to download all your google docs from shell

Tags: bash, wget, google-docs-api

I learned how to download single google doc. But I am trying to make a script that downloads all my data in text format and then merges them in 1 text file. So, I wonder how to implement downloading part so that 1 can get zip file with all my files just as you do with web browser. Here is my newb script to get single file. Hope you can suggest some tweaks that make it more effective.

```
#!/bin/bash
token=$(curl -s https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -d Email=user.name@gmail.com -d Passwd=blahblah -d accountType=GOOGLE -d service=writely -d Gdata-version=3.0 |cut -d "=" -f 2)
set $token
wget --header "Gdata-Version: 3.0" --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$3" "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID=${resourceId}&exportFormat=txt" -O /tmp/${file[$i]}.txt
```

Here I specify single **resourceId**, as you see. Should I just push many **resourceId**-s in download link to get them all or there is better way?

Comment: You are using `set` to set the positional parameters, but not using them. You are using an array called "file" but not defining it or the index variable "i" (and there's no loop which would seem to be implied). Is there more to your script?

Comment: Yes, there is small loop, since the script is to download 4 files at a time, feeding 4 different resourceId-s. Somehow, I got to using set by trial and error, I think it could be done better. This "token" is an array of 3 "key=value" pairs separated by newline and I needed just the last item out of this array.

Comment: Last array item: `${token[@]: -1}` (the space is required when there's a negative offset) or the third item: `${token[2]}` (zero indexed). You could eliminate the `cut` by using the last element syntax. It would work whether the output from `curl` looks like "parts=part1 part2 part3" or "parts = part1 part2 part3". Do you need to use both `curl` and `wget`?

Comment: I tried both ${token[@]: -1} and in my script, did not work. The token looks like:
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
All I need is to paste the "value3" into wget string, that's why I use curl in the 1-st line. I could find way to achieve google-docs download in 1 wget command.

Comment: `token=$(curl ... )` (no `cut` and no `set`) `wget ... auth=${var##*=} ...` But back to your question: without seeing the rest of the script (at least the loop) it's hard to see what's needed.

Comment: The main question here is: what's URL for downloading all files from google docs. The rest is really not so crucial, script can be good or bad, but not knowing that URL even the coolest scripts won't help. I guess, I would need to sniff http traffic to get that.

Comment: @Temujin do you have full code that download from Google Docs?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a non-native tool I would highly recommend: http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

However, considering the age of this question, you may have already figured this out.

Comment: "8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice."

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Archive feed of the Documents List API to export your documents as a zip file:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_archives_of_documents_and_files